# Playing Counter Strike 1.6 on Wirless LAN

Tags: counter-strike

We have a LAN made up of multiple computers connected via Wifi and we use to play CS on this LAN, there is a proxy server (SQUID) between us and internet.

We are unable to play CS multiplayer any more now. Have they blocked the ports with proxy server? If so what can we do? Search for open ports https://superuser.com/questions/421030/find-ports-not-blocked-by-proxy-server ?

Answer (score 1):

You can play on Wireless LAN even if ports are blocked .
If "they" have blocked ports then you cannot play online or on Steam.

Use local IP of Local Server(on LAN) to connect.

Answer (score 1):

SQUID can't interfere in your LAN gaming there must be some WiFi connection problem, you must check the  connection properly and If you are still having problem then there must be some game error. For this solution you must download Steam as a solution. You can download it from [here](http://store.steampowered.com/about/?snr=1_4_4__11).